# Encoding issue when performing aggregation to find average by group in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have a dataset of items inside an orders collection:

```
> db.orders.find()
{"_id" : ObjectId("1a5"), "date": ISODate("2021-06-07T00:00:00Z"), "category": "A", "total": 150},
{"_id" : ObjectId("1a6"), "date": ISODate("2021-06-07T00:00:00Z"), "category": "B", "total": 175},
{"_id" : ObjectId("1a7"), "date": ISODate("2021-06-07T00:00:00Z"), "category": "A", "total": 200},
```

and I want to find the average value of total by category in pymongo. The category is sometimes not present but total is always present.

I tried this in pymongo

```py
pipeline = [
    {"$group": { "_id": "$category", "average": {"$avg": {"$total"}}}}
]

db.command('aggregate', 'orders', pipeline=pipeline, explain=True)
```

and I got an error

```
InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: {'$total'}, of type: <class 'set'>
```

Performing a similar query in the mongo shell directly works fine though:

```
> db.orders.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$category", average: {$avg: "$total"}}}])
{ "_id" : "A", "average" : 175 }
{ "_id" : "B", "average" : 175 }
```

I checked using Compass that the values of total are stored as int32 so I don't understand the error message and how to fix it. I tried searching around as well but most of what I found about this error were about inserting entries into the db instead of aggregating them. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra braces around `"$total"`; try:

```
pipeline = [
    {"$group": { "_id": "$category", "average": {"$avg": "$total"}}}
]
```

Comment: Thank you! Can't believe I didn't see it and spent so much time searching

Comment: MongoDB can give you bracket-blindness! :)